# Use Nvidia GPU as primary video output and AMD GPU as OpenCL on arch

Tags: linux, amd-radeon, nvidia-graphics-card, gpgpu

How can I use my Nvidia Titan X as my main video output with proprietary driver and an AMD Fury X as a OpenCL card?

Is it possible to have Catalyst and Nvidia proprietary driver installed at the same time?